# Text Beside a toggle switch

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for a toggle switch. All I want to do is have some text to the left of these switches but whatever I do it breaks and messes up the switches. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #34A7C1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section id="middle">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch4" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch4">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch5" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch5">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</section>
```

Not sure why it won't let me just float text to the left.

Comment: Share you css code please.

Comment: @MarioJuniorTorresPerez Here's my css

Answer (score 0):

Use a table tag to organize it.

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
<TD align="right">Box2</TD>
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"    id="myonoffswitch5" checked>
```

Comment: Thanks but that, still doesn't work any other ideas of where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must to create a swicth container for each switch and create a another   child that content you text inside a

tag or  like you want it. You need put

> display: inline-block;

In the switch and text container. Look that I edit the .onoffswitch class and add another else named .switchtext

Here's is my sample

```css
  .onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;

}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px;
}

.switchtext{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="middle">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div class="swicth-container">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch4" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch4">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="switchtext">
      <p>
      TEXT
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    
<div class="swicth-container">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch5" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch5">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="switchtext">
      <p>
      SOME TEXT
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```